# From windows linux subsytem could not connect windows 10 psql

Tags: django, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have install psql10 in my windows 10. It is installed successfully and running in port 5432 properly. From linux subsystem i am trying to connect my app with psql 10. But getting this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

One possible solution that i am thinking is to install psql in linux subsystem but i thought there might be way from that i can connect psql. I am a new user of windows10.

Comment: You'll need to show how you are trying to connect to it.

Comment: hello sir, i am actually using same what django official doc mention ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases ). Another thing i like to mention, I have a machine where i do use linux environment and this works fine. For some experimental purpose i am trying this with windows10 in another machine and having this trouble.